# Can branches of a mindmap merge to another node?

Tags: treenode, mindmapping, mindmap

I do lots of mindmaps recently and I often face a problem which is that I can't merge branches. Such as a node has branch1, branch2, branch3 and branch4, and I find branch3 and branch4 can tend to another node. But, it seems both MindNode and Xmind don't support this function and are all one straight way.

[image]

Can any software provide the function in the red box?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be looking for a [concept mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_map) software rather than a mindmapping one. [Unlike mind maps, concept maps are general graphs rather than trees.](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Alternatives_to_FreeMind#Concept_map_editor)

Also Wikipedia has [an article that lists some concept- and mind-mapping software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_concept-_and_mind-mapping_software).